# Viewing int32/float32 as bytes inside Numba nopython function

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Anyone could point me to the way of viewing of int/float Numpy array as a bytestring inside Numba-nopython function?

What I'm trying to achieve is to try to use Numba-nopython function as an alternative to np.array.tobytes() as it is a too slow for semi-large arrays.

In my environment `arr.tobytes()` in this code takes 1.1 seconds, which is just unacceptable for such a small array:

```
arr = np.random.ranf(15000000).astype(np.float32)
str = arr.tobytes()
```

This delays plagues our TensorFlow Serving GRPC calls with unnecessary slowdown.

Comment: Does it actually need to be a python `bytes` object?  `arr.view(np.uint8)` will view the data as bytes and is essentially free

Comment: I will check it out if GRPC TensorProto could be set this way.

Comment: I'd like to see an answer to the original question. I need `bytes` because I'm using it as a dict key. @chrisb

Comment: I tried a few different ways of doing this at https://repl.it/@TomGoBravo/numba-bytes but none are supported.

Comment: I also created https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5149